# Android set custom image off of label text

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image

I currently have a timer that ticks and changes the label to count down the seconds.
Is is possible and if so how do i change and image in and image box to a custom value for each for example
Label=1   imagebox1=1.jpg
Label=2   imagebox1=2.jpg
Or would it the easier to go off the timer tick value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a Sprite class. Then I would use the value from the ticker to cycle through the various bitmaps I need.  But if the images are small enough resolution combine them in one Image and use an AniSprite...

```
import android.graphics.*;

public class AniSprite {

public RectF target;
public Rect source;
public Bitmap bitmap;
public int width;
public int height;
public float posx;
public float posy;
public int frames;
public int curframe = 0;

public AniSprite(Bitmap bitmap, float posx, float posy, int width, int height, int frames) {
    this.drawview = drawview;
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.posx = posx;
    this.posy = posy;
    this.frames = frames;
    source = new Rect(curframe * width, 0, (curframe * width) + width, height);
    target = new RectF(posx, posy, posx + (width), posy + (height));
}

public void animate() {
    curframe++;
    if(curframe >= frames){
        curframe = 0;
    }
    source = new Rect(curframe, 0, (curframe) + width, height);
}

public void setSourceRect(Rect rect) {
    source = rect;
    curframe = rect.right/width;
}

public void ChangePos(float posx, float posy) {
    this.posx = posx;
    this.posy = posy;
    source = new Rect(curframe * width, 0, (curframe * width) + width, height);
    target = new RectF(posx, posy, posx + (width), posy + (height));
}

}
```

So in this class instead of cycling through different bitmaps, I made one big bitmap that has each frame of the animation one after another. (use photoshop) the parameters tell the position on the screen x and y, the width and height of the frame (so each image), and the number of frames.

executing AniSprite.animate() will switch the target to the new frame, thus you draw your sprite as

```
canvas.drawBitmap(sprite.bitmap, sprite.source, sprite.target, null);
```